# Override recursion limits for __get and __set on the same property

Tags: php, php-internals

Is there a way to Override recursion limits for `__get` and `__set` on the same property.  I want to be able to handle the second reentry differently than the first entry.

This code example isn't practical but the simplest to make the point.

```
 class Foo {
     public function __set($name,$value){
         print "$name entered\n";
         this->$name = $value; // want it to recurse here
     }
 }

$a = new Foo();
$a->baz = "derp";
print $a->baz;

// should get (cannot test at the moment)
// baz entered
// derp  <- you get derp because the current php implementation creates an instance variable from the second call to __set
```

My Internet is down so I'm typing on my phone so typos are likely.

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know, what you mean. This way the __set is not recursing (by the way, I think you mean `this->$var = $args;
`).

Comment: Your right, it isn't recursing and that is the problem.  Php prevents it from recusing and creates an instance variable instead.  I was wondering if there is a way to relax the recursion restriction on __set() and __get().

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980996/get-and-set-not-behaving-as-expected as this issue is related to that issue, in that I am trying to find a more elegant solution than making _set/_get methods.

Comment: I don't get the problem you are trying to solve. You talk about recursion, but there's no recursion, you say you try to find a more elegant solution than __get() and __set() magic methods, but you DO use them. Please go in front of a full terminal and edit your question, explaining properly what the problem is.

Comment: Flavius, I think you are not seeing where the recursion occurs (or should occur had php not been holding our hands) this missing the entire point.  Perhaps this will be more clear:

Comment: Flavius, I think you are not seeing where the recursion occurs (or should occur had php not been holding our hands) this missing the entire point.  Perhaps this will be more clear: in __set() when I call $this->$name it should create a recursive call to __set() with the same arguments as the current call which should be an infinite recursion since it isn't caught, however php prevents this recursion from happening as it only allows one call to __set() with a particular variable name on the stack at a time.  This prevents me from trying to catch this situation myself and handling it differently

Comment: Also I said more elegant than _get/_set not __get/__set.  See the other link that I posted for what I am wanting to use the solution to this problem for.  The solution to that problem identified the existence of this proble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a old question, but I think this is what you actually were looking for.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    private $_data = array();
    public function __set($name,$value){
        print "$name entered\n";
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name){
        if(array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)){
            return $this->_data[$name];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }

$a = new Foo();
$a->baz = "derp";
print $a->baz;
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4h0-an7

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with that syntax. Just call `__set` directly instead, e.g.:

```
class Foo {
     public function __set($name, $value) {
         print "$name entered\n";

         $this->__set($name, $value);
     }
}
```

Comment: No this would not work the way I need it to. I think to do what I near would require me to modify the zend engine and recompile php.  Which is also unacceptable, oh well.

Comment: @kporter: Since you didn't say what you needed it to do other than "recurse here", I cannot help you further without additional information.

Comment: Well for one I did say on the same property but you added an underscore thus creating a new property.  Two I want to be able to use $this->$name to recurse (btw you could have done $n = $name . '_' then $this->$n and archived the same results but still not what Im looking for.  It has to be $this->$name and it may not be possible in the current php implementation of __set().

Comment: I added the underscore to prevent infinite recursion. Your whole question is without a point really, there's isn't any valid reason to do such a thing.

Comment: Actually there is, see the link in the comments above.  The idea is that when someone calls $foo->bar = "derp"; it will in turn call $thsi->set_bar("derp") now the parent class has a default handler defined in __call() for this but a subclass can define its one set_bar() method and define a different behavior but the catch is the derived class cannot use $this->baz = "derp".

Comment: I have to require derived classes to use a special _set_bar method but instead I would rather inspect the stack and see if I am currently in the child frame of a __set with the current  $name passed as an arg.  It would provide a cleaner interface for the other developers I work with.  For now they will just have to use _set_baz("derp").

Comment: @kporter: I most understand what you're saying, but there are bits that are still unclear. Maybe you'd want to [join the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and better explain your use case (or edit your question with the above details to help us visualize this).